# Rewrite based on Query Parameters

Tags: php

I using PHP on IIS Server and I need to rewrite a url with query parameters to url without query parameters

My url is: http://localhost/?page=info and I want that open http://localhost/info

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this
1st you need to make rewrite engine enabled on your php config on server
2nd make .htaccess file
then put this code in it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

maybe that answer your question? hope so

Answer (score 0):

Put this code into `.htaccess` file.
To keep the prefix and replace the last part with a query string

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^id=
RewriteRule ^root/pages/(.+)$ /root/pages/?id=$1 [L]
```

The RewriteCond is needed to prevent a rewrite loop.

Comment: It´s not working. When open a url http://localhost/info or http://localhost/?page=info is not rewrite to http://localhost/info and show a 404 error